# Evince Document Viewer theme not working

Tags: gnome, themes, evince

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 with gnome-shell 3.24.2 
I'm using the Gnome-OSX-II-2-6-NT theme. The problem is the theme isn't getting applied on the document viewer, and I'm seeing the transparent background behind the pages. I checked with another [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217802/strange-gtk3-issue-with-audacious-and-evince-document-viewer) but it did not work. I am attaching screen-shots of the [theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb8uK.png) and [document viewer window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDX5q.png). Any help will be appreciated.